# Microsoft Visual C++ 2017 installer forces automatic reboot

Tags: windows-10, reboot, installer, visual-c++

We produce a Windows application the installs Microsoft Visual C++ 2017 Redistributable (x86) 14.16.27033.

On a Windows 10 computer, after the Visual C++ 2017 library install completes, a window pops up for a fraction of a second saying "A reboot is required to continue with the installation. After rebooting, re-run the installation. Click OK to reboot now or Cancel to reboot later" with an arrow over the OK button.

Then the computer reboots.

The developer says he can't reproduce that problem, and that there's no way to stop this - says there's no flag to stop the reboot.

The computers that reboot have a pretty standard set of applications with Office 365 and Web browsers.

Does anyone have an idea as to how to stop the Visual C++ installer from forcing an immediate reboot?

Thanks.

Tom

Comment: The `Visual C++ 2017 Redistributable` does not require a reboot.  It sounds like the application that you developed, has part of the installation process, a script that produces that message.  I would continue to talk to the developer to determine the cause of the requirement to reboot.  **It is not being generated by the Microsoft Visual C++ 2017 installer.**

Answer (score 0):

The Visual C++ 2017 Redistributable is installed because it is required for some
other component(s) in the installation.
It is rather that component that causes the restart.

It is abnormal that the dialog has disappeared without giving you
the option of booting later, which is the case with the standard Windows dialog.

This all points to some strange practices in the installation package itself.
You should address the complaint to the developer.
If he cannot reproduce the problem, it just means that he is testing in a different
environment, or one that has the Visual C++ 2017 Redistributable already installed.

Answer (score 0):

Add `/norestart` to the end of yours. So

```
vcRedist_x64.exe /passive /install /norestart
```

Answer (score -1):

I had the same issue with vcRedist_x64.exe installing redistributables 14.23.27820
of VisualStudio 2019.

I called the exe with following Parameters:

vcRedist_x64.exe /passive /install